Question about Fermat's theorem on extrema
We have the inequality: $a^x \geq x+1$
Find the value of $a$
My book says:
Let $f(x)=a^x-x-1$, we have:
$f(0)=0$ and
$f(x) \geq 0 \Leftrightarrow f(x) \geq f(0)$ thus 0 is the minimum of $f$, therefore using Fermat's theorem we conclude that:
$f'(0)=0$ and from here that $a=e$, that's all understandable to me. But then it says we need to check if for $a=e$ $f(x)$ does indeed have a minimum at 0 because: "the opposite of Fermat's theorem doesn't hold true". I don't understand the logic.
We've already shown that irregardless of the value of $a$:
$f(x) \geq f(0)$,
therefore no matter which number $a$ is $f(0)$ will always be a minimum, so why do we even need to check the value $a=e$?

You have that $f'(0)=0$, and you got $a=e$. Did you prove that it's a minimum? Maybe it's a maximum

I proved that it's a minimum though.
The inequality a^x≥x+1 is true for at least one number a.
Now we have f(x)=a^x-x-1
f(0)=0 and f(x)≥0<=>f(x)≥f(0) so f(0) is definitely a minimum for the correct number a for which the inequality holds. Assume we have the number a for which the inequality holds, in that case f(0) will necessarily be a minimum because the inequality f(x)≥f(0) will necessarily be true. So f'(0)=0<=>.......a=e. Why would i need to recheck? I've already shown that for the correct number a, f(0) is indeed minimum. I don't get it.

You showed that $f(x) \ge f(0)$ follows from the assumption that $f(x) \ge 0$ for all $x$. What you've proved is that if such a function $f$ exists, then $a$ must be $e$. But you have not shown that $f(x) = e^x - x - 1$ is indeed always $\ge 0$. It could still be that the inequality has no solution.

But f(x)≥0 was not an assumption. Also it is given, that the inequality is true for one a
